# query result taking time to load

Tags: mysql, performance, left-join

I have a query that fetches data from Six tables but it takes too much time to fetch data.The browser loads and shows sometimes nothing as a result.When I run this query in the MySQL database, it takes a long time to execute.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS movies.*,
curriculums.name AS curriculum,
teachers.name AS teacher,
movie_sub_categories.name AS sub_cat_name,
movie_categories.name AS cat_name
FROM movies
LEFT JOIN curriculums on movies.curriculum_id = curriculums.id
LEFT JOIN teachers on movies.teacher_id = teachers.id
LEFT JOIN movies_movie_sub_categories on movies.id = movies_movie_sub_categories.movie_id
LEFT JOIN movie_sub_categories on movies_movie_sub_categories.movie_sub_category_id = movie_sub_categories.id
LEFT JOIN movie_categories on movie_sub_categories.movie_category_id = movie_categories.id
ORDER BY id LIMIT 0, 50
```

Here all of my table structure
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Provide table structures with `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` for all tables involved  and provide `EXPLAIN query`.. Without this information we are unable to help you

Comment: Please check index in the table. All the column should be indexed which are used in join query On clause

Comment: @RaymondNijland I have placed screenshot of my table schema

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. Use edit functions to inline, not link, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained. And never give a diagram without a legend/key.

Comment: Hi. If you want to learn about coding for performance, read everything in the MySQL manual re indexes & optimization. And there are many, many generic resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a very exciting query -- it simply delivers the first 50 rows of whichever table `id` belongs to.  When `JOINing`, *please* qualify columns so we know what is going on.

Do you really need `LEFT`?

Assuming you need `LEFT` and `id` belongs to `movies`, then this should run a lot faster:

Meanwhile, find how many rows there are in `movies` only once, so you don't have to compute it every time.

```
SELECT  movies.*, curriculums.name AS curriculum,
        teachers.name AS teacher, movie_sub_categories.name AS sub_cat_name,
        movie_categories.name AS cat_name
    FROM  ( SELECT id FROM movies ORDER BY id LIMIT 0, 50 ) AS m
    JOIN  movies USING(id)
    LEFT JOIN  curriculums AS c  ON movies.curriculum_id = c.id
    LEFT JOIN  teachers AS t  ON movies.teacher_id = t.id
    LEFT JOIN  movies_movie_sub_categories AS mmsc  ON movies.id = mmsc.movie_id
    LEFT JOIN  movie_sub_categories AS msc  ON mmsc.movie_sub_category_id = msc.id
    LEFT JOIN  movie_categories AS mc  ON msc.movie_category_id = mc.id
    ORDER BY  m.id
```

Please use `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; we need to see if you have sufficient indexes, such as

```
mmsc:  INDEX(movie_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

the table movies_movie_sub_categories needs to have an index on movie_id and a separate index on movie_sub_category_id. Without those two indexes the query builder will be forced to scan every record twice (since the query has two separate join clauses that reference that table)

Comment: Thanks for your answer i will check with this .